# DaoExample , Android Studio: R package does not exisists

Tags: android, android-studio, greendao

I've just downloaded DaoExample from https://github.com/greenrobot/greenDAO. After that, I copy grade/ and gradlew/ from a HelloWorld project of Android Studio into DaoExample/ folder, then: ./gradlew build in my terminal.

but I get the error: R package does not exisists.
Please, help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have a gen folder for code that is generated for you automatically. And this is where R lives.if you compile your program you will see all the R errors disappear.only problem is its catch 22. You can't compile if you have other errors in your code. So trust me ignore any R errors but fix the rest.save your file saving it alone will magically "fix" many errors.clean your project will also help and when you go to run it with no compile time errors wala R appears.now you get to deal with runtime errors